# Android list separator and order

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am writing an application for managing students time table and I'm having problem with presentation. I want to have all items sorted by time they start and if there is next day there should be shown list separator with date.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    String day = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY"));
    if(day.equals(lastDay)){
        separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else{
        separator.setText(day + " " + dayOfWeek);
        lastDay = day;
        separator.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0099CC"));
    }
}
```

Unluckilly, I am facing 2 problems. 1st items are not sorted at all, maybe but 10 first, and 2nd it seems to me I have no control when each cell is drawn thats why algorithm with compering last day doesnt work at all and I have separator between every single entry, beside few first cells... Any ideas how can I solve this? (Btw. data is fetched from sqlite db)
Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sorting whatsoever in the code in your answer, so I cannot help you with the 1st issue.

BTW, if possible, you should sort your data on the SQLite level - it will be faster than any Java code. If it's not possible (for example your sorting criteria cannot be expressed as a sqlite query), you should sort the data before passing it to the adapter. In this case you should probably create your own BaseAdapter subclass.

The second issue is the expected behavior of CursorAdapter. The bindView are called on demand, so they will be called for the subsequent items when you're scrolling down, but when you start scrolling up, it will be called for the items appearing on the top of the screen. Read more about views recycling in Android adapters.

If you want to section your data I recommend creating an adapter with two view types - one for the section header, the other one for the actual item. Calculate the positions of added section items in swapCursor() call and call different code in newView/getView.

Answer (score 0):

1st, you will need to sort your data by the day column. You need to do this when query the database and get the cursor. The sort string will look something like this:

```
"DAY ASC"
```

2nd, this is the really tricky thing. If you did this yourself you would have to remap the cursor positions and set different view types on getView like chalup said. I've made a library that does all of this for you though called [SectionCursorAdapter](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter/). To implement your this for yourself extend SectionCursorAdapter and do the following.

```
@Override
protected Object getSectionFromCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex("DAY");
    String day = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    return day;
}
```

That will give you a new section for each day. Mattering on what you return you could make it by week or month as well.